# Copying 2D arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, copy, 2d, copying

I'm trying to copy some 2D arrays of strings into an another one.
I have 2 arrays that look like this:

```
char *tabA[SIZE];
char *tabB[SIZE];
```

I want to copy `tabA[indexA]` to `tabB[indexB]` but `strcpy(tabB[indexB], tabA[indexA])` doesn't work at all, program gets crashed (but compiler doesn't return any errors).

Comment: Did you malloc() everything as necessary before strcpy()'ing?

Comment: Copy the pointer of the memory it points to?

Answer (score 1):

> strcpy(tabB[indexB], tabA[indexA]) doesn't work at all, program gets
>   crashed

Possibly because `tabB[indexB]` is not initialized and contain `NULL` or invalid pointer.

**Solution**
Allocate memory to `tabB` statically using a 2D array as `char tabB[SIZE1][SIZE2] = {{0}};` or dynamically as `for(i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) tabB[i] = malloc(...);` or using `strdup`. In case of dynamic allocation, make sure you `free` and don't leak the memory.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `memcpy` from `string.h`, prototyped like this:

```
void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);
```

> The memcpy() function copies n bytes from memory area src to memory
>   area dest.

For more detail read the manual of `memcpy` using the command `man memcpy` on a terminal.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const size_t SIZE=8;

int main()
{
  char *data[] = {"jan", "fev", "mar", "apr", "mai", "jun", "jul", "aug"};
  char *data2[SIZE];

  memcpy(data2, data, sizeof(char*) * SIZE);

  for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    printf("data = %s, data2 = %s\n", data[i], data2[i]);

  return (0);
}
```

Comment: @MohitJain `sizeof(char*)` is not `sizeof(char)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
tabB[indexB] = strdup(tabA[indexA]);
```

works perfectly :)